# Can an appender mapping have more than one level mapped?

Tags: c#, log4net

I am new to log4net, I tried searching for a answer but I could not find one. When you create a mapping for a `appender`, can you specify multiple levels?

For example currently I have

```
<appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >
  <applicationName value ="(snip)" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="(snip)" />
  </layout>
  <mapping>
    <level value="FATAL"/>
    <eventLogEntryType value="Error"/>
  </mapping>
  <mapping>
    <level value="ERROR"/>
    <eventLogEntryType value="Error"/>
  </mapping>
  <mapping>
    <level value="WARN"/>
    <eventLogEntryType value="Warning"/>
  </mapping>
  <mapping>
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <eventLogEntryType value="Information"/>
  </mapping>
  <mapping>
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <eventLogEntryType value="Information"/>
  </mapping>
</appender>
```

Can I somehow turn it in to

```
<appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >
  <applicationName value ="(snip)" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="(snip)" />
  </layout>
  <mapping>
    <level value="FATAL"/>
    <level value="ERROR"/>
    <eventLogEntryType value="Error"/>
  </mapping>
  <mapping>
    <level value="WARN"/>
    <eventLogEntryType value="Warning"/>
  </mapping>
  <mapping>
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <eventLogEntryType value="Information"/>
  </mapping>
</appender>
```

It did not throw any errors when I tried it but I have not done enough through testing to see if it behaved as I was expecting it to behave. Can this be done, and is the way I did it the correct way to do it if it can?

Comment: All the config examples on the log4net site show multiple mappings specified. But it would be good to know if you can specify multiple levels in one mapping.  I know that multiple appenders can use that syntax though.